# Is there a faster way to subset a sparse Matrix than '['?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm the maintainer of the seqMeta package and looking for ideas on how to speed up the bottleneck of splitting a large matrix into smaller pieces a large number of times.

### Background

The seqMeta package is used to analyze genetic data.  So you have a group of subjects (n_subject) and a number of genetic markers (n_snps).   This leads to a n_subject x n_snp matrix (Z).  There is also a data frame that tells you which snps get grouped together for analysis (typically which snps comprise a given gene).

While Z may be large, it is quite sparse.  Typically less than 10%, and sometimes around 2%, of the values are non-zero.  A sprase matrix representation seems like an obvious choice to save space.

A current project: nsubjects ~15,000 and nsnps ~2 million, with over 200,000 splits.

As the data size continues to grow I've found the time limiting factor tends to be the number of groupings, not the actual size of the data.  (See the below example runtime is a linear function of n_splits for the same data)

### Simplified Example

```
library(Matrix)

seed(1)

n_subjects <- 1e3
n_snps <- 1e5
sparcity <- 0.05


n <- floor(n_subjects*n_snps*sparcity) 

# create our simulated data matrix
Z <- Matrix(0, nrow = n_subjects, ncol = n_snps, sparse = TRUE)
pos <- sample(1:(n_subjects*n_snps), size = n, replace = FALSE)
vals <- rnorm(n)
Z[pos] <- vals

# create the data frame on how to split
# real data set the grouping size is between 1 and ~1500
n_splits <- 500
sizes <- sample(2:20, size = n_splits, replace = TRUE)  
lkup <- data.frame(gene_name=rep(paste0("g", 1:n_splits), times = sizes),
                   snps = sample(n_snps, size = sum(sizes)))

# simple function that gets called on the split
# the real function creates a cols x cols dense upper triangular matrix
# similar to a covariance matrix
simple_fun <- function(Z, cols) {sum(Z[ , cols])}

# split our matrix based look up table
system.time(
res <- tapply(lkup[ , "snps"], lkup[ , "gene_name"], FUN=simple_fun, Z=Z, simplify = FALSE)
)

##    user  system elapsed 
##    3.21    0.00    3.21  

n_splits <- 1000
sizes <- sample(2:20, size = n_splits, replace = TRUE)  
lkup <- data.frame(gene_name=rep(paste0("g", 1:n_splits), times = sizes),
                   snps = sample(n_snps, size = sum(sizes)))

# split our matrix based look up table
system.time(
res <- tapply(lkup[ , "snps"], lkup[ , "gene_name"], FUN=simple_fun, Z=Z, simplify = FALSE)
)

##    user  system elapsed 
##    6.38    0.00    6.38

n_splits <- 5000
sizes <- sample(2:20, size = n_splits, replace = TRUE)  
lkup <- data.frame(gene_name=rep(paste0("g", 1:n_splits), times = sizes),
                   snps = sample(n_snps, size = sum(sizes)))

# split our matrix based look up table
system.time(
res <- tapply(lkup[ , "snps"], lkup[ , "gene_name"], FUN=simple_fun, Z=Z, simplify = FALSE)
)

##    user  system elapsed 
##   31.65    0.00   31.66
```

Question: Is there a faster way to subset a Matrix than '['?  Or other approached I'm missing?

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve your problem, but using `parallel::mclapply` gives a significant speed-up on multicore systems.

Comment: I'm not sure the bottle neck is on `[`. It seemed to be more about how tapply works, how the matrix is split. Maybe you can try other split/aggregate method like plyr, dplyr. apply family not necessarily means good performance.

Comment: @dracodoc I'm pretty sure it is [.  Replace tapply any type of looping structure (for loops, *apply, anything from dplyr/plyr) and the performance only gets worse AFAICT.

Comment: I'm wondering if a long format data frame/data.table can have advantages over the sparse matrix. You can have column `subject`, `snps`, `value`. One subject can have m snps in m rows. You only have the non-zero value in data frame. Then you can add a gene column according to snps. Now you can do all kinds of aggregation/calculation in this data frame/data.table. The disadvantage is your existing functions are probably based on matrix, and there may be a one time cost of converting matrix to data frame. Though I think the performance boost could be substantial especially if you use data.table.

Comment: @BrianDavisStats you should definitely try to use `data.table` - represent sparse matrices in a coordinate form (also called triplet form) and than just use fast data table joins instead of `[` subsets. It is definitely possible, but I'm too lazy to dig :-) At least I hope this comment will help you.

Comment: @dracodoc and Dmitriy-Selivanov I'll definitely give triplet form another look.  I tried it when dplyr first came out and the tradeoff was the objects were MUCH larger.  Now that there are database backends for data.tables and dplyr maybe that shouldn't be as much of a concern.    There are also quite a few details my simple example fails to address, but I think they’d be solvable, especially if I could get a order of magnitude speed increase.

Comment: I found this question and answer useful, so trying to give back based on what I found. For my application (subsetting a sparse matrix by colnames) it was 20% faster to look up indices and subset by indices than to subset by colnames directly. `matrix[, which(matrix@Dimnames[[2]] %in% names_to_subset)]` was 20% faster than `matrix[, names_to_subset]`.